# Colorful Python Interpreter for Windows

Tags: python

Is there a colorful Python interpreter to download other than using the Windows Command Prompt?

I am new to Python and don't know much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IDLE](http://docs.python.org/library/idle.html) is a pretty friendly way to get started (it comes with Python)

[IPython](http://ipython.org/) is another possibility. The easiest way to install it is via [EPD Free](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php) or [Python(x,y)](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/).

Comment: Side note: to get tab completion and color in IPython on Windows, you need to also install [pyreadline](http://ipython.org/pyreadline.html) (see [here](http://wiki.ipython.org/IPython_on_Windows)). That is likely not the case if you get one of the distributions Thomas mentions, but if using it with an interpreter installed by itself you will need it. Basically, if you find IPython does not have color or tab completion, look at the links included.

Comment: If you install ipython using pip it will download dependencies like pyreadline for you. Best way to install pip is to install distribute first (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#distribute-setup-py), then do "easy_install pip". Then do "pip install ipython"

Comment: But there are several more dependencies if you want to get the new Qt console for IPython (namely ZMQ and PyQt). One of those distributions is definitely the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [IdleX](http://idlex.sourceforge.net). It provides a lot of additional functionality to IDLE and it's simple to get started. Download, extract, and then run idlex.py.